# NSTimer method calls multiple times

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I am developing one application,in that i have one requirement.onTyping method calls on textfield text change.when i enter first letter on textfield ontying method get called and timer starts &pause method called after 10 sec,pause method get called on continue on typing.But i want call pause method on last letter typing.how can i achieve this one

```
-(IBAction)onTyping:(id)sender
{

   // [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(pause) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    if(timer==nil)
    {
        timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(pause) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
    [self fadeIn];

}
-(void)pause
{    
    [self fadeOut];

}
- (void)fadeIn
{
     NSlog(@"fadeIn");


}
- (void)fadeOut
{
   NSlog(@"fadeOut");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

call that method `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` method of `UITextFieldDelegate` like bellow...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
        [self pause];
    return YES;
}
```